# PHP: array_diff remove all elements that not having a numeric character in the string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm displaying a files using `glob` and I don't want to manually input each file name to remove in element using `array_diff`, I'm looking for other way to improve this by searching file name that having a number and remove those elements.

```
$dirs = 'D:/'.$type_of_store.'/LAB/'.$theSub.'/'.$subSub;                       
$theDirs = array_diff(glob($dirs.'/*.xml', GLOB_BRACE), 
array(
 '.',
 '..',
 'D:/'.$type_of_store.'/LAB/'.$theSub.'/'.$subSub.'/PosDataUpdatesStatus.xml',
 CommCenterManagerConfig.xml,
 ExternalReferences.xml
)
);
```

The file output

```
CommCenterManagerConfig
ExternalReferences
PosDataUpdates-2016-10-27 094721
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 104425
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 110226
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 014654
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 062805
```

Is there other way to search string that having a number and remove it in array element?

My files should be display only string that contains number

```
PosDataUpdates-2016-10-27 094721
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 104425
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 110226
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 014654
PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 062805
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply "grep" through the input? And I suggest that you try to match a bit more precise to prevent surprises in future...

Take a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
$folders = [
    '.',
    '..',
    'CommCenterManagerConfig',
    'ExternalReferences',
    'PosDataUpdates-2016-10-27 094721',
    'PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 104425',
    'PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 110226',
    'PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 014654',
    'PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 062805',
];
$pattern = '/^PosDataUpdates-[0-9-]{4}-[0-9-]{2}-[0-9-]{2}\s[0-9]{6}$/';
print_r(preg_grep($pattern, $folders));
```

The output of above example is:

```
Array
(
    [2] => PosDataUpdates-2016-10-27 094721
    [3] => PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 104425
    [4] => PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 110226
    [5] => PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 014654
    [6] => PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 062805
)
```

---

If you apply that strategy to your file system access task, then something as simple as that will be the result:

```
<?php
define('BASEDIR', './data/');
$folders = glob(BASEDIR . '*.xml');
$pattern = '/PosDataUpdates-[0-9-]{4}-[0-9-]{2}-[0-9-]{2}\s[0-9]{6}/';
print_r(preg_grep($pattern, $folders));
```

The output of that will be:

```
Array
(
    [2] => ./data/PosDataUpdates-2016-10-27 094721.xml
    [3] => ./data/PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 104425.xml
    [4] => ./data/PosDataUpdates-2016-11-21 110226.xml
    [5] => ./data/PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 014654.xml
    [6] => ./data/PosDataUpdates-2016-11-22 062805.xml
)
```

Obviously the question of paths and file name extensions can be addressed as required.